# Can't load images users uploaded with arc on prod on heroku

Tags: heroku, elixir, automatic-ref-counting, plug

I use arc to save users uploads and add to the db. On localhost everything works fine with (in `lib/app_web/endpoint.ex`)

```
plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/uploads", from: Path.expand("./uploads"), gzip: false
```

I can't understand where I can save uploads on heroku so I can access them with `https://app.herokuapp.com/uploads/images/...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing with uploading files direct to Heroku is that they get deleted every time your dyno stops/restarts. So you need to store those files outside of your Heroku application. One solution is to use [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3) (it's quite cheap if you don't have lots of data, like half dollar a month if you store 20 GB and have 100GB of traffic).

From the [Heroku help pages](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted):

> The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to
>   the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is
>   shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the
>   filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many
>   container based systems, such as Docker, operate.
>
> In addition, under normal operations dynos will restart every day in a
>   process known as "Cycling".
>
> These two facts mean that the filesystem on Heroku is not suitable for
>   persistent storage of data. In cases where you need to store data we
>   recommend using a database addon such as Postgres (for data) or a
>   dedicated file storage service such as AWS S3 (for static files). If
>   you don't want to set up an account with AWS to create an S3 bucket we
>   also have addons here that handle storage and processing of static
>   assets https://elements.heroku.com/addons